# How to affect formatting of dynamically created label text in c#

Tags: c#, formatting

I think this should be a pretty easy question to answer but I can't seem to figure it out.
I am adding text to labels from a sqldatasource in c#. All of that works, but I want to be able to format the text. I want to 1) be able to change the format to 0.00 (instead of a string of decimals) and I would also like to be able to add words before the text.  I assume I need to somehow use the string.format command but can't figure out how to work it in. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's my code below:

```
DataView dvSql = (DataView)DeskSummary.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
foreach (DataRowView drvSql in dvSql)
{

    Desk.Text = drvSql["Deskname"].ToString();                  
    MarginLabel.Text = drvSql["margin"].ToString();
    CurrentCI.Text = drvSql["comp_index_primarycomp"].ToString();
    WalMartCurrentCI.Text = drvSql["comp_index_walmart"].ToString();
    ForecastMargin.Text = drvSql["margin_forecast"].ToString();
    WalMartForecastCI.Text = drvSql["comp_index_walmart_forecast"].ToString();
    ForecastCI.Text = drvSql["comp_index_primarycomp_forecast"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the format argument to the `ToString()` method like so:

```
MarginLabel.Text = drvSql["margin"].ToString("0.00");
```

However, as you said you wanted to prepend some text. Therefore, I recommend:

```
MarginLabel.Text = String.Format("Prepended text {0:0.00}", drvSql["margin"]);
```

*Note: I just picked one of your labels; I'm not sure which ones get special formatting treatment.*

Comment: or he could also do string.Format("PreText {0:###.###}", Convert.ToInt32(inputString)); what if the number is 1000.00 would the format still make up for that.. just curious..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I wound up using the second format with prepended text and it worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

use the

```
string.Format("This is a before text {"0"},your param)
```

// you can add as many variables and `{""}` string literals as you need just make sure that  you separate the variables with a `","`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
string stringNumber = "5123.34214513";
decimal decimalNumber = Decimal.Parse(stringNumber);
string output = String.Format("Your text: {0:0.00}", decimalNumber);

Console.WriteLine(output); //Your text: 5123.34
```

This works if the column is of type `string`

Answer (score -1):

`String.Format()` will do what you need for prepending/appending text values,

```
string.Format("prepend text {"0"} append text", paramString)
```

But if you want to actually format the value you are getting back from SQL, then you would need to use `String.Format()` on that value as well as possibly some RegEx expressions and/or `.ToUpperCase` or `.ToLowercase` for your capitalization... something like.

```
var capitalizedString = paramString.subStr(0,1).ToUppercase + paramString.subStr(1, paramstring.Length);
string.Format("Prepended text {"0"} plus appended text", capitalizedString);
```